What do negative feature attributions in machine learning mean?
Maybe this is not a particular smart question, but I fail to understand negative feature attributions (importance scores) from algorithms such as IntegratedGradients in explainable (interpretable) machine learning. An attribution of 0 for a feature means this feature was not important for the prediction, and a positive score means this feature was important for the prediction, but what does a negative score mean?
I read different things. One time I read that positive scores mean the feature is important for class 1 in binary classification, and negative for class 0. Is that what they are?  However, in one other web article (https://medium.com/geekculture/feature-attribution-in-explainable-ai-626f0a1d95e2) it says this: The score could range from a positive value that shows its contribution to the model’s prediction, to a zero that would mean the feature has no contribution, to a negative value which means that removing that feature would increase the probability of the predicted class. For example, the image background has been used as a feature in certain object recognition tasks. If an attribution algorithm assigned it a negative score for a hand gesture recognition model, it would mean that removing background pixels would improve the recognition of gesture class.
If you could help me, that would be great!
Thanks a lot,
Thomas
